# Finding if the two events are independent with $P(A \cap B')$.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have $P(A \cap B') =0.4$ .

$P(A') = 0.6$ and $P(B) = 0.5$.

I know $P(A) = 1-0.6 = 0.4$

and $P(A) P(B) = 0.2$

I am not sure what to do with  $P(A \cap B')$ to make it $P( A \cap B)$?

Comment: Well, $P(A)$ must be the sum of $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A\cap B^c)$ so...

Comment: Quick glance, we would have expected $P(A\cap B')$ to be less than $P(A)$ since $(A\cap B')\subseteq A$, but we see that they are equal despite $B'$ having probability less than $1$...

Comment: Since independent, $P(A \text{and} B^c)=P(A)(1-P(B))=P(A)-P(A)P(B)=P(A)-P(A\text{and} B)$  , like lulu mentioned